# What is a manifest file when not Java-related?

Tags: c++, c, manifest, android-manifest

What is a manifest file used for when the term is used in discussions concerning Linux, Android, and C++?

I can't seem to find a good, basic definition that isn't java-related.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an answer to that, because it's specification-dependent jargon. However in general I'd wager that if you hear that expression it's indicating a text file that accompanies and holds metadata for a program or library (I totally ripped the wording from Wikipedia, btw).

Comment: It's only plagiarism if I don't cite my sources!

Comment: Very true... +1 for not plagiarising then!

Answer (score 1):

Every Android application must have an `AndroidManifest.xml` file (with precisely that name) in its root directory. The manifest presents essential information about the application to the Android system, information the system must have before it can run any of the application's code.

Read further [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

NOTE: I am not sure I understand your Q correctly, because the Q title and the content in the Q are not the same. The above info is about `Manifest file in Android`